# angular js dynamic binding of data with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json

```
[ { "qpid": "41", "qbid": "4", "presentqb": "banktest", 
    "difficulty": [ 0, 0, 2, 0, 0 ], 
    "selQ": [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] }, 
  { "qpid": "41", "qbid": "6", "presentqb": "bank 29th", 
    "difficulty": [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 ], "selQ": [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] } ]
```

I want a div according to the number of enteries in json with dropdown. the number of dropdown depends on selQ.The value in dropdown ranges according to the the difficulty in json.when the dropdown value changes it should get into the selQ of json. 
I used the below code

```
<div class="well" id="selectedQBs" style="height:200px" 
     ng-repeat="(k,selQB) in selQBs">
   <ul>
      <li>{{selQB.presentqb}}
          <a href ng-click="selQBs.splice($index, 1)">
              <span class="btn btn-mini btn-danger"><strong>x</strong></span>
          </a>
          <div>
             <div id="{{selQB.qbid}}" 
                  ng-repeat="sq in selQB.selQ track by $index" 
                  ng-hide="allocationtype == 4">

                 <select ng-model="selQBs[k].selQ[$index]" 
                         ng-options="n for n in range(selQB.difficulty[$index])">
                 </select>

             </div>
          </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**Through the above code i am not able to bind the changed value of dropdown with the corresponding div's selQ**